# unable to use custom database initializer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building a simple MVC application for managing a library. For development purposes, I would like the EF to drop and recreate the database everytime the model changes, as well as filling it with some sample data. At this moment I struggle at getting the initializer to work. The Initializer class looks like this:

```
public class LibraryInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LibraryContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(LibraryContext context)
    {
        // sample data to be writted to the DB
    }
}
```

And the context class looks like this:

```
public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public LibraryContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<LibraryContext>(new LibraryInitializer());
    }
}
```

At this moment I get the following error:

> Member 'Database.SetInitializer(IDatabaseInitializer)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Based on many guides available on the Web, this is the way to use the initializer, but I have no idea why this error occurs. 
Any help would be greatly appraciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In `C#` you can't access `static` members from instances. You must access `static` members using the name of the type. Use full type name.

```
 System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<LibraryContext>(new LibraryInitializer());
```

`DbContext` has a `Database` property which is an instance of `System.Data.Entity.Database` class. When you write `Database` in your `DbContext` it points to that instance and since you can not access static methods from instances you get the error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that pretty much solved the problem. Well, the thing is, when I check any tutorials/blog posts explaining how to build initializers (don't wanna point to any specific website), none of them actually show the full `System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer..` name. Is it something with my code that forces to use it or it's not mentioned anywhere as "everyone should know that"?

Comment: I had the same issue recently, and I had my database classes in a folder called Database, which caused the namespace to look like MyService.Database. In that case I had to fully specify System.Data.Entity.Database otherwise, you would not have to do that.

Comment: you need to add using System.Data.Entity; into your using directions - otherwise it will try to use the Database property of your DbContext class, because it can't find the class.

Comment: I got the error evening when adding a System.Data.Entity using directive. Only by fully qualifying the type as dotctor explains did I solve the problem.