# System.TypeLoadException with Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, entity-framework-6

I'm running into following error after i've deploid my website in IIS and try to view the page in the browser.

> Could not load type 'DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinContext' from
>   assembly 'DienstbulletinApp'.    Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinContext' from assembly
>   'DienstbulletinApp'.

When i run my application in visual studio 2019, i don't have this error. 
I have removed the contexts from my webconfig file but nothing seems to be the sollution

```
 <contexts>
      <context type="DienstbulletinApp.DAL.DienstbulletinAppContext, DienstbulletinApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral">
        <databaseInitializer type="DienstbulletinApp.DAL.DienstbulletinAppInitializer, DienstbulletinApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
```

DienstbulletinContext:

```
 public class DienstbulletinAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public DienstbulletinAppContext() : base("name=DienstbulletinDBConnectionString")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DienstbulletinAppInitializer());

        }
        public DbSet<Dienstbulletin> Dienstbulletins { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Voertuig> Voertuigen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Opdracht> Opdrachts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DienstbulletinDetail> DienstbulletinDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Locatie> Locaties { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gebruiker> Gebruikers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Persoon> Personen { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OpdrachtType> OpdrachtTypes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Aandachtspunt> Aandachtspunten { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gsm> Gsms { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Persoon>().ToTable("t_Persoon");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Voertuig>().ToTable("t_Voertuig");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gebruiker>().ToTable("t_Gebruiker");
            modelBuilder.Entity<OpdrachtType>().ToTable("t_OpdrachtType");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Opdracht>().ToTable("t_Opdracht");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Dienstbulletin>().ToTable("t_Dienstbulletin");
            modelBuilder.Entity<DienstbulletinDetail>().ToTable("t_DienstbulletinDetail");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Locatie>().ToTable("t_Locatie");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Aandachtspunt>().ToTable("t_Aandachtspunt");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Gsm>().ToTable("t_Gsm");

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }
    }
```

I'm using .Net Framework version 4.0.30319 and ASP.NET 4.7.3535.0

I know that all DLL must be referenced in the solution but the files where i get an error are my own classes of my application.

here's the full error:

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinAppContext' from assembly 'DienstbulletinApp'.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +95
>      System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError) +63
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +46
>   [InvalidOperationException: Failed to set database initializer of type 'DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinAppInitializer, DienstbulletinApp' for DbContext type 'DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinAppContext, DienstbulletinApp' specified in the application configuration. Entries should be of the form 'key="DatabaseInitializerForType MyNamespace.MyDbContextClass, MyAssembly" value="MyNamespace.MyInitializerClass, MyAssembly"' or 'key="DatabaseInitializerForType MyNamespace.MyDbContextClass, MyAssembly" value="Disabled"'. Also verify that 'DatabaseInitializerArgumentForType' entries are present for every parameter of the database initializer constructor. See inner exception for details. Consider using the  configuration section to set the database initializer (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468).]
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type requiredContextType, String contextTypeName, String initializerTypeName, Boolean isDisabled, Func`1 initializerArgs, Func`3 exceptionMessage) +327
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializerFromLegacyConfig(Type contextType) +644
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InitializerConfig.TryGetInitializer(Type contextType) +39
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetServiceFactory(Type type, String name) +513
>      System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +87
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.AppConfigDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +187
>      System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +78
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +115
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key) +41
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +159
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +171
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +269
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +20
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +69
>      System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
>      System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +59
>      System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +61
>      DienstbulletinApp.Controllers.GebruikerController.Login() in D:\Plastic\Dienstbulletin\Dienstbulletin\Controllers\GebruikerController.cs:24
>      lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__0() +80
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +387
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__4() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +40
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +602
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +195
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +128

Comment: Can you confirm that the .DLL is being published when you push your code to the IIS? Make sure the property `Copy Local` for the  DLL reference `DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinContext`  is set to true.

Comment: @salli Do you mean "Copy to Output Directory" set to true. does that generate a DLL?  DienstbulletinApp.DienstbulletinContext is just a class in my solution

Comment: Ah I see.  Yes, sorry, I misunderstood.  I think the error might be caused by failure to initialize the context.  Try changing `Database.SetInitializer(new DienstbulletinAppInitializer());` to  `System.Data.Entity.Database.Database.SetInitializer(new DienstbulletinAppInitializer());` as mentioned in this stackoverflow post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953401/unable-to-use-custom-database-initializer

Comment: In some case, the error message could occur when something wrong happened in DB. Have you checked your database log? Because your application user has been changed from login user to application pool identity

Comment: @Jokies Ding the database log had indeed an error that the login failed. After adding the 'IIS APPPOOL\.NET v4.5' user the error in the sql log disapeard but the error in my browser still remains.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error removing the version and culture=neutral from contexts solved the issue:

```
<contexts>
  <context type="DienstbulletinApp.DAL.DienstbulletinAppContext, DienstbulletinApp">
    <databaseInitializer type="DienstbulletinApp.DAL.DienstbulletinAppInitializer, DienstbulletinApp" />
  </context>
</contexts>
```